# Spring application behaves differently when adding AOP Advice

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

I'm using Spring Integration for a project for which a logging aspect was created. Using AOP annotations the aspect is configured. The application works as expected with the logging annotation commented. But if the annotation is uncommented then the app still work, but the boolean field applySequence magically becomes false.

[image: applySequence == true at the target object] 
[image: but applySequence == false at the proxy level]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Nothing magical here... You are looking at the proxy NOT the actual object in use (the one with value true is the actual object (the target)). The proxy is only a wrapper for the actual object with all the fields initialized to default values.

Comment: Hi Denium, Thank you for the response. But isn't the proxy supposed to have the same values as the underlying object.

Comment: No it shouldn't. The proxy is nothing more then a wrapper that adds behavior to the actual object. It doesn't hold anything itself (apart from its own state needed for the proxy mechanism).

Comment: But if you refer to the above pictures you could see that it's different indeed. Look at "applySequence". Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ofcourse because 1 is the proxy (which only has the default value which for a boolean is `false`) the other is the target with the actual property set.